# Remote Machine Info Access | Without JMX

Tags: java

Hi i need to get the CPU usage of remote system in java without using JMX.

I have the code to test in local machine,but not remote machine

```
 try{
            Sigar session = new Sigar();
            System.out.println(session.getNetInfo());
            String temp,fdigit;
            int cpuUsage=0;
            double freeCpu = 0;
            DecimalFormatSymbols simbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            simbol.setDecimalSeparator('.');
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##",simbol);
            while(true){
            temp="";    
            cpuUsage=0;
            Thread.sleep(900);  
            CpuPerc cpuPerc = session.getCpuPerc();
            freeCpu = cpuPerc.getCombined()*100;
            freeCpu = Double.valueOf(df.format(freeCpu)); 
            temp=""+freeCpu;  
            fdigit=temp.substring(temp.indexOf(".")+1);
            if(Integer.parseInt(fdigit)>=4){
                cpuUsage=Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(".")));
                cpuUsage=cpuUsage+1;                
            }
            System.out.println(cpuUsage+"%");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I googled about ,but i could not find any samples without using JMX.

So i hope our stack overflow users will help.Let me know asap..

Answer (score 0):

In [RHQ](http://www.jboss.org/rhq) we fallback to sigar if there is not JMX support for the service. But we run an agent on the monitored platform, that sends the data over the wire. AFAIK, there is no way to do that completely remotely.

Comment: :Thanks for ur reply.I am not knowing about RHQ.I need to access remote maching system info(cpu usage).Whether is there any way to get using ip address alone or someother info i need.please let me know?

Comment: In IBM's TADDM product, they do everything on *nix by simply logging into the box and running shell commands.  For Windows, I believe it uses the Windows Management APIs.  If one was forced to do it, I think that might be a valid option.